# How to redirect error message to mail to somebody

Tags: bash, email, redirect

Yes, I don't want a bash script. I just want error message redirected to email.So I wrote a command like this:

```
python youku.py 1>/dev/null | mail -s test xx@icloud.com
```

I know this is not right, I just want to know how to let it be right.
Thanks!

Comment: If your program has a different exit based on whether it ran successfully or not - the unix standard is to return 0 on success, error is anything non-zero, you could run the python program with the 2> going to a file and then check $? != 0 to see if you need to cat error_file.txt | mail -s  test xx@icloud.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
python youku.py 2>&1 >/dev/null | mail -s test xx@icloud.com
```

Comment: So the order of 2>&1 and >/dev/null  is important.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this
python youku.py 2>&1 2>&1 | mailx -s "Subject" xx@icloud.com